# Insert a character in a string at a certain position iMacros

Tags: imacros

I'm getting in an int with unknown number of digits, I want to add a "." decimal point 2 digits from the end.

example:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:price EXTRACT=TXTALL    'the price text are 48852
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}  
'processing...
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}       'print 488.52
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=CLASS:price EXTRACT=TXTALL
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var n = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.trim(); n.substr(0, n.length - 2) + '.' + n.slice(-2);")
' print 488.52 '
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```